# Printing XML into HTML with python

Tags: python, html, xml

I have a TextEdit widget in PyQt that I use to print out a log in HTML. I use HTML so I can separate entries into color categories (red for error, yellow for debug, blue for message, etc), but this creates a problem. Most of the debug messages are XML. When I use appendHtml on the widget, it strips out all the tags.

How can I pretty print XML in an HTML document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) can help you. It will convert the characters `'&'`, `'<'` and `'>'` in the string to HTML-safe sequences. That is enough to prevent interpretation of xml tags.

```
>>> cgi.escape('<tag>')
'&lt;tag&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

A cdata section might help.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/CDATASection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA